# Any formal methods to evaluate $\int x^x\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Are there any formal methods to evaluate   $I$ ?

$$I = \int x^x\mathrm dx$$

Online calculators don't give any output. So, are there any known methods to evaluate at least some definite integrals like
$\int_1^2 x^x\mathrm dx$ , $\int_1^ex^x\mathrm dx$ or any ?

Comment: See [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) from Wikipedia.

Comment: You can approximately find them by using $x^x$'s Taylor expansion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802256/the-nth-derivative-of-xx/4605115#4605115

Comment: This has no closed form antiderivate, you have to compute a definite integral numercially.

Comment: @soupless I thought for a neat technique atleast for the definite integral though it isn't now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\int x^xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx)

Comment: @TymaGaidash ( I asked for any techniques for definite integral while the question linked is only of indefinite integral). Despite it's high votes, I don't know why it didn't came as similar question while I was posting and ensuring to avoid duplicacy.